# Postgres table queries not responding

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have been trying to truncate a table using SQlWorkbench. Suddenly, SqlWorkbench got freezed, while the truncate was in progress. I had to kill workbench from taskmanager. But now none of the queries are working on the table on which the truncate was aborted abruptly. For other tables queries are working fine. Need help, as I have to upload fresh data on the same table. Currently I am not even able to drop the table. What can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can try query pg_stat_activity and check whether the truncate command still running or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the `TRUNCATE` got stuck behind a lock, and then you killed the front end, while `TRUNCATE` kept running.

Connect to the database as superuser and examine the `pg_stat_activity` view; you should see some long running transactions.

Use the function `pg_terminate_backend` to kill these sessions by their `pid`.

Comment: how exaclty do you call pg_stat_activity?